# LayoutY of GridPane not affected by ScrollBar Listener

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane that i fill dynamically, then I display it, the problem is: if the rows are so many, then the rows in the bottom don't get displayed, what i want is to add a scrollbar so that I can display all of the rows, here is the code but it's not working:
[image]
[image]

```
BudgetManager bManager = new BudgetManager();
    List<Debt> debts = bManager.getDebts();
    GridPane topLevel = new GridPane();
    topLevel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    int row = 0;
    double totatB = 0, totalS = 0;

    for (Debt d : debts) {
        //fill GridPane
    }

    ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
    sc.setMin(0);
    sc.setMax(350);
    sc.setVisibleAmount(20);
    sc.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    sc.setUnitIncrement(10);
    sc.setBlockIncrement(50);
    sc.setPrefWidth(20);
    sc.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) -> {
            topLevel.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
        }
    });
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().addAll(topLevel, sc);
    HBox.setHgrow(topLevel, Priority.ALWAYS);

    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 1200, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

**SOLVED**
here is the solution, thanks to keuleJ, using ScrollPane instead of ScrollBar:

```
    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    GridPane topLevel = new GridPane();

    scroll.setContent(topLevel);
    scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
    scroll.setFitToHeight(true);

    Scene scene = new Scene(scroll, 1200, 600); // Manage scene size
```

Comment: shouldn't you use a ScrollPane for that? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html

Comment: yes I already try that and it works, BUT I want to display the gridpane in Center (not TOP LEFT) and it should always grow if the user resize, scrollPane does not provied Alignment property as far as I know, that is why I use an HBox

Comment: What about fitToWidth or fitToHeight? Did you study the docs:
 The ScrollPane allows the application to set the current, minimum, and maximum values for positioning the contents in the horizontal and vertical directions. These values are mapped proportionally onto the layoutBounds of the contained node.

ScrollPane layout calculations are based on the layoutBounds rather than the boundsInParent (visual bounds) of the scroll node. If an application wants the scrolling to be based on the visual bounds of the node (for scaled content etc.), they need to wrap the scroll node in a Group.

Comment: @keuleJ THANKS man that is exactly what I needed: scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
Can please put the answer again so I can mark it as the answer for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fitToWidth or fitToHeight properties.

See the docs: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html